# How to show a div block only when a particular input is focused using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, onblur, onfocus

I tried using the `onfocus` function in JavaScript for displaying a block when a password field is focused in a .php file (designed using bootstrap 4) but when I click on the passsword field nothing happens.

I tried using jQuery code for the same, still got no results.

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById("password");
var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
var capital = document.getElementById("capital");
var number = document.getElementById("number");
var length = document.getElementById("length");

myInput.onfocus = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
}


myInput.onblur = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">
                        <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
                    </span>
    <input required type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password">
  </div>

  <div id="message">
    <p id="letter" class="invalid">A <b>lowercase</b> letter</p>
    <p id="capital" class="invalid">A <b>capital (uppercase)</b> letter</p>
    <p id="number" class="invalid">A <b>number</b></p>
    <p id="length" class="invalid">Minimum <b>8 characters</b></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your code works. When I click on the input field the DIV shows, when I click out of it the DIV disappears.

Comment: But on my server nothing is happening , I am using Wamp server,

Comment: Your code worked for me as well. I would check to see where else those events could be getting handled. I would guess there is another event handler that is calling stopPropagation

Comment: The server shouldn't matter, this code runs entirely in the browser.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the JavaScript console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three possible problems with your code.

1) The `form-group` div was not closed, so your browser may have mis-interpreted the code, messing up its structure.

2) When the page loads, no events have triggered; so by default, your `message` div will be visible. When you focus on `password` then un-focus on it, `message` does disappear. To fix this, add `style="display: none;"` to your `message` div.

3) Most importantly, your script needs to be executed AFTER the document loads. You can easily do this by putting all of your script in a JQuery document.ready function:

```js
$(function(){
    //Do everything here. This function will only execute after the document is ready.
}
```

Or, as I did, simply put your `script` tag at the BOTTOM of the page. This way, your script will load after the rest of the page has loaded.

The reason behind this is simple. When your browser loads a page, it loads each element one by one, more or less. Scripts execute as soon as they're loaded. So if your script runs before the rest of your HTML is loaded, nothing will happen.

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="input-group-prepend">
  <span class="input-group-text">
   <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
  </span>
  <input required type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password">
 </div>

 <div id="message" style="display: none;">
  <p id="letter" class="invalid">A <b>lowercase</b> letter</p>
  <p id="capital" class="invalid">A <b>capital (uppercase)</b> letter</p>
  <p id="number" class="invalid">A <b>number</b></p>
  <p id="length" class="invalid">Minimum <b>8 characters</b></p>
 </div>
 <script>
  // this is my javascript code
  var myInput = document.getElementById("password");
  var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
  var capital = document.getElementById("capital");
  var number = document.getElementById("number");
  var length = document.getElementById("length");

  myInput.onfocus = function() {
   document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
  }


  myInput.onblur = function() {
   document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
  }
 </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```js
const $ = (selector) => document.querySelector(selector);
const input = $('#password');
const message = $('.message');

input.addEventListener('focus', (e) => {
    message.style.display = 'block';
});

input.addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
    message.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
.message {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
        </span>
        <input required type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password">
    </div>

    <div class="message">
        <p class="letter invalid">A <b>lowercase</b> letter</p>
        <p class="capital invalid">A <b>capital (uppercase)</b> letter</p>
        <p class="number invalid">A <b>number</b></p>
        <p class="length invalid">Minimum <b>8 characters</b></p>
    </div>
</div>
```